# When should i use async/await and when not?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

Should i use async/await from now on (c# 5) everytime when i don't require the outcome of an method immediatelly (Task<>) or i have to fire a one-off method (void)?

Should i use it in all the cases when i used the Task class in C# 4 and pushed work to the Backgroud threads?

Should i use it only in cases when i used asynchronous .Net Framework Methods?

Confused.

I am basically looking for a simple explanation in which cases i should use await/async and when not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`async` / `await` may be used when you have *asynchronous operations*. Many operations are naturally asynchronous (such as I/O); I recommend `async` for all of those. Other operations are naturally synchronous (such as computation); I recommend using synchronous methods for those.

You can use `Task.Run` with `async` for background work if you need to run synchronous code asynchronously. I explain on my blog why this is [better than `BackgroundWorker` and asynchronous delegates](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html).

You can also use `async` to replace other forms of asynchronous processing, e.g., the `IAsyncResult` style.

You **should** use `async` in any situation where you have an asynchronous operation.